# Implement the gecoder gem in nested resource loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-geocoder

I implemented the geocoder gem based on the tutorial on http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

This is a part of the house show view template

```
- @house.location.nearbys(20, {:order => :distance, :units => :km}).each do |house|
   %li
    = link_to house.name, house_path
    (#{city.distance.round(2)} KM)
```

This show al other houses with the distance in KM, so this works fine.

I already showed on the same house page all the cities of the region where the house is located, like this:

```
%ul.tags
 - @region.cities.each do |city|
   %li= link_to city.name, country_region_city_path(@country, @region, city)
```

Question: How can i implement the geocoder gem in the @region.cities loop so the visitor can see on the house page how many KM is it to drive from the house to the cities?

Thanks...remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoded objects should have a `distance_from` method.  `@house` should have that method if you follow Ryan Bates' tutorial.

Check the docs for how to use it: 
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#location-aware-database-queries

You basically just need to ask @house it's distance from the city (within your cities loop)

Answer (score 0):

yep i did it...it was not so dificult i expected...

```
  - @region.cities.each do |city|
     %li
      = link_to city.name, country_region_city_path(@country, @region, city)
     %li 
      = @house.location.distance_from([city.latitude,city.longitude])
```